# Website size to mobile

Tags: css, mobile

I have a website in build, if I adjust the browser (reduce the width to phone size) it all squishes perfectly, in theory optimized for mobile.

However any mobile will automatically fit it to the screen, which means on mobile it currently looks a little small without zooming in.

Is there an easy fix to this?

Comment: can you show how much small does it looks on mobile? and have you tried on other mobile browsers?

Comment: Instead of resizing the browser, you should try using the device emulation that many browsers come with nowadays. Heres the chrome version: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode. Screenshot would also help.

Comment: Usually this is because you're missing the viewport tag in the head of your html

Comment: Try placing this in your head section - <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"><!-- adaptive layout, matches page to device width --> Don't know if this is your problem for sure without more code, but if it is, here's some additional information on responsive meta tags - http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/

Comment: Exactly, try what @Talkingrock suggested first.

Comment: What Talkingrock says is probably the issue. Noticed his comment after I submitted my answer.

Comment: Just noticed all these comments! Thank you all very much. <meta name="viewport" content="width=device=width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0,"> did exactly what I needed. Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that you haven't set the viewport to device width. Mobile browsers default behavior scales down the site to fit all content. Use the following meta tag in your `<head>` section to make your responsive layout work.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device=width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0,">
```

Comment: Thank you so much, worked like a charm!!!!! Really appreciate that a lot. I was trying viewport variations like crazy, but that makes sense now :)